# Book Identification: 90's YA Fantasy maybe with mirror in it

Tags: story-identification

I vividly remember this book cover but that is it. I'm pretty sure it was a Scholastic and the cover was cut in half from top right to bottom left with the image of a girl on one half and a boy on the other. he is upside down though. If you were to turn the book over it would look completely normal except the girl would be upside down. I can not remember the title for the life of me. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 10):

Without a plot summary to work with it is hard to come up with an answer, but the book might be *The Boy Who Reversed Himself* by William Sleator.  The book has been published with several covers including this one:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I believe you may be talking about a book called "Of Two Minds" by Carol Matas and Perry Nodelman. It was a two part series involving a headstrong princess and the prince she is supposed to marry. They both have special powers but end up losing them when they get trapped in a different land and have to work together to get home.

[image]

Comment: Wow, this is a perfect match.  +1 from me.